# Difference between rows Mysql Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table which is having four fields:

```
trip_paramid, creation_time, fuel_content,vehicle_id
```

I want to find the difference between two rows.In my table i have one field fuel_content.Every two minutes i getting packets and inserting to database.From this i want to find out total refuel quantity.If fuel content between two packets is greater than 2,i will treat it as refueling quantity.Multiple refuel may happen in same day.So i want to find out total refuel quantity for a day for a vehicle.I created one table schema&sample data in sqlfiddle. Can anyone help me to find a solution for this.here is the link for table schema..http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4cf36

Comment: What is the desired output for the sample data posted in the fiddle demo?

Comment: Input parameter for this query should be date and vehicle_id.So output will contain three columns.Date,Vehicle_id&Refuel Qty

Comment: And what about the `date` would it be the latest fuel time i.e the max(date) or what?

Comment: What i need is total refuel quantity for day(eg:Inupt may be 2012-11-08 and vehicle_id=14).So i want to get total refuel quantity of vehicle 14 for date 2012-11-08

Comment: also one more thing to remember is this table contains 10 different vehicles data(like veh1,veh2,veh3...)

Comment: @vivek You say "If fuel content between two packets is greater than 2,i will treat it as refueling quantity", I guess you mean the difference between two consecutive packets. It that right?

Comment: two consecutive packets for a particular vehicle.bcoz table contains details of multiple vehicles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good query.

Parameters (vehicle_id=13) and (date='2012-11-08') are injected in the query, but they are parameters to be modified.

You can note that have I chosen an expression using `creation_time<..` and `creation_time>..` in instead of `DATE(creation_time)='...'`, this is because the first expression can use indexes on "creation_time" while the second one cannot.

```
SELECT
SUM(fuel_content-prev_content) AS refuel_tot
, COUNT(*) AS refuel_nbr
FROM (
  SELECT
  p.trip_paramid
  , fuel_content
  , creation_time
  , (
    SELECT ps.fuel_content
    FROM trip_parameters AS ps
    WHERE (ps.vehicle_id=p.vehicle_id)
    AND (ps.trip_paramid<p.trip_paramid)
         ORDER BY trip_paramid DESC
         LIMIT 1
    ) AS prev_content
  FROM trip_parameters AS p
  WHERE (p.vehicle_id=13)
  AND (creation_time>='2012-11-08')
  AND (creation_time<DATE_ADD('2012-11-08', INTERVAL 1 DAY))
  ORDER BY p.trip_paramid
) AS log
WHERE (fuel_content-prev_content)>2
```

Comment: @Skrol29..thanks for quick response..i will test it and let u know

Comment: thank u so much..is it possible to find fuel pilferage/Leakage using same query?.Because output contains two columns REFUEL TOTAL and FUEL PILFERAGE.How fuel pilfferage is calculated is difference between previous fuel content is more than 2 ,i will treat it as fuel pilferage/leakage.In your query is it possible to include this data also??In your existing query refueling is working fine..

Comment: @vivek You can delete the clause `WHERE (fuel_content-prev_content)>2` and replace the column `refuel_tot` with `SUM(CASE WHEN fuel_content-prev_content>=2
    THEN fuel_content-prev_content
    ELSE 0 END
   )`. Delete the `refuel_nbr` because it become erroneous. Then you can add new calculated columns bases on "fuel_content" and "prev_content". But I did not understand your definition for pilferage calculation.

Comment: as i described in my question,i am  getting fuel content data in every two minutes and inserting to database.so if difference between two consecutive packets is more than two,i will consider it as fuel pilferage,so what my question is using a single query is it possible to find total fuel loss and refueling quantity..in above comment what u suggesting is two seperate queries for fuel loss and refuel quantity..is it possible to combine both in a single query??..if u have any other suggestion in calculating fuel loss for a day ??

Comment: @vivek : Yes you can have it in the same query, that what I was trying to say, and trying to give the steps. In order to give the SQL, you have first to express the formula of the new columns. Anyway, here is an example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6cac5/1

Comment: it is working...but one thing it is giving total refuel quantity for time range.Instead of that is it possible to get daily wise refueled quantity for a date range.If we give an input of From Date as 2012-11-10 and To date 2012-11-11 as input then is it possible to generate an output Like on 2012-11-10 total refuel qty is 10.2012-11-11 total refuel qty is 30.

Comment: @vivek This is not a difficulty. It's a minor enhancement in the query. But you are extending your first problem. It would have been better to give all elements in the first statement.

Comment: @skro..i tried this for getting daily report..http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da662/10

Comment: thanks @skrol..pepole like u make this site more beautiful..thank u so much.

Answer (score 0):

Test it:

```
select sum(t2.fuel_content-t1.fuel_content) TotalFuel,t1.vehicle_id,t1.trip_paramid as rowIdA,
t2.trip_paramid as rowIdB,
t1.creation_time as timeA,
t2.creation_time as timeB, 
t2.fuel_content fuel2,
t1.fuel_content fuel1,
(t2.fuel_content-t1.fuel_content)  diffFuel
from trip_parameters  t1, trip_parameters  t2
where t1.trip_paramid<t2.trip_paramid 
and t1.vehicle_id=t2.vehicle_id 
and t1.vehicle_id=13
and t2.fuel_content-t1.fuel_content>2 
order by rowIdA,rowIdB
```

where (rowIdA,rowIdB) are all possibles tuples  without repetition, diffFuel is the difference between fuel quantity and TotalFuel is the sum of all refuel quanty.

The query compare all fuel content diferences for same vehicle(in this example, for vehicle with id=13) and only sum fuel quantity when the diff fuel is >2.

Regards.

Comment: I need difference between fuel quantity..not time difference

Comment: @esmoreno..still i am confused..i need total refuel quantity for a day.multiple refuel may happen in same day.So i need sum of all these refuel quantities.

Comment: i think ur query having some issue..bcoz in that one row is compared against all the rows.

Comment: @esmoreno..it is finding difference between only two rows.Actually i want get difference between consecutive rows of particular vehicle and sum of all that differnece quantity.

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17d5d/1 ..in this case refuel qty is only 15,but it showing "105"

Comment: I believe that the output is correct. If you erase the sum in select clause and only put the difference t2.fuel_content-t1.fuel_content, you can see that the sum is correct.